# Correctly display the GNU screen session title in status bar

Tags: linux, grep, gnu-screen

in GNU screen, I want the title of the session to be displayed in the status bar. It is working but not exactly as I wanted.

I have the following backtick defined in my .screenrc:

```
backtick 100 30 30 sh -c 'screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*"'
```

As I said, it does display the screen-session title but also the PID of that session; it shows, for example, something like

```
1234.foo
```

where foo is the name of that session.

My question: How can I remove the numbers including the dot to only show the session's name? (I am, obviously, not too familiar with grep ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I said in my comment to the answer from yoshikaw, I am not able to use it (although I am sure there is a way to do this).

I have, however, found another way to do what I want using the `tr` command:

```
backtick 100 30 30 sh -c 'screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*" | tr -d [:digit:]' | tr -d .
```

The first `tr` command deletes the PID (the numbers) and the 2nd `tr` command deletes the dot.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, using awk to get the session name from the output of `screen -ls` easily.

```
screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*" | awk 'BEGIN { FS="."} { print $NF }'
```

in my test environment:

```
(default sessionname)
$ screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*"
12817.pts-5.hostname
$ screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*" | awk 'BEGIN { FS="."} { print $NF }'
hostname

(sessionname is 'foo')
$ screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*"
12817.foo
$ screen -ls | grep --color=no -o "$PPID[^[:space:]]*" | awk 'BEGIN { FS="."} { print $NF }'
foo
```

If you use the latest version of GNU Screen (>= 4.1.0), you can use `%S` escape string on caption or hardstatus character to display sessionname.

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "[%S] some strings you like..."
```

Comment: that is precisely working as you described it, thanks! When I put it into my .screenrc, I have however the problem that the ' infront of BEGIN leaves the command... So my subsequent question is very simple: how to use nested or multiple ' in this case...?

Comment: mentioning `awk` reminded me of `tr`: here I can use `tr -d [:digit:]` which removes the numbers in front of `foo` (I could, of course, also remove the dot with `"."` but I somehow like the style of having a dot there). 
It also works in the `.screenrc` file with by limited knowledge about using `'` inside of `'` ;-)